# Unable to send an email using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, email

I am unable to send the email using the below script

```
$fromemail = "pap@domainname.com"
$users     = "pap@domainname.com"
$Server    = "smptserver.domainname.com"

Send-MailMessage -From $fromemail -To $users -Subject "Disk Space Monitoring Report" -Body "Hello world" -Priority High -SmtpServer $server
```

This was the error message displayed below at the output screen:

```
Send-MailMessage : The remote name could not be resolved:
'smptserver.domainname.com'
At line:10 char:2
+  Send-MailMessage -From $fromemail -To $users -Subject "Disk Space Mo ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Comment: can you resolve the server address using dns? ping/nslookup?

Comment: The name `smptserver.domainname.com` could not be resolved. This looks like a placeholder but it contains a typo (SMTP not SMPT). Perhaps you misspelled the real server name as well?

Comment: Hi Everyone, thanks for taking out your time and providing your inputs, i am still unable to get the code working.

Comment: Then please answer the question. Can you resolve the server name manually?

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to write the variable as a string also use the ip address of your smtp server not the dns name

```
> [string]$stmp = 0.0.0.0 

 [string]$emailfrom = email@company.com

> [string]$emailtoo = email@company.com (if you add more than one email

> address here add a [] at the end of string like so [string[]]$emailtoo)
```